# Why do css columns cut off content in safari. column width also wont work right

Tags: css, safari

http://rotanadan.com/columntest/columntest.html

The columns in the dropdown are all messed up in safari and cut off the content, and when i try to use column-width it just breaks and doesn't work at all.

Comment: You should ad more details to describe your problem, provide code and if possible provide a fiddle.

Comment: Its just a simple little sample at that link, should I paste all the code here when its in the link?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this myself. Declare a `width` on `.dropdown-menu` and the problem will go away. You may have to compute this from your intended column width.

The `column-width` property only specifies a minimum, and if the browser can't "fit" the minimum within the width of the `.dropdown-menu`, it will revert to a single column.

Internet Explorer, Firefox, and Chrome seem to "do what you mean", as they seem to take the `column-count` and compute an appropriate column-width based on the contents of each column, assuming the maximum width of the container to be infinite. Safari does something ... weird, as if it's smooshing everything into some default of 100px. I suspect it is a bug in Safari, but don't know enough about it to be certain.